# 1С Битрикс. Отправка уведомления о прочтении письма

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Пытаюсь реализовать отправку уведомления о прочтении писем получателем. В интернете насерфил такие хейдеры:

```
X-Confirm-Reading-To: <your_mail_addr> и Disposition-Notification-To: <your_mail_addr>
```

Но в стандартное событие `CEvent::Send` не могу найти как добавить эти хейдеры.

```
$headers .= "X-Confirm-Reading-To: $xconf\r\n";  
$headers .= "Disposition-Notification-To: $notif\r\n";
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как привильно это сделать?

Comment: Правильно сделать - пойти в шаблон письма и там дополнительные хедеры прописать.